# How to enable GPU for flash player 11?

Tags: flash, gpu, flash-develop

I just install Flash Player 11 and SDK 4.5 (hero), and test it with a small program. But I find it is still using "software" to simulate 3D API, and

```
trace("driver info: " + _context3D.driverInfo);
```

output

```
driver info: Software
```

I'm using windows 7, directX works properly, and option "-swf-version 13 -use-gpu" is already added in compiler arguments.

Who can tell me how to enable GPU in Flash Builder?

UPDATE:

context3d is constructed as :

```
private var _context3D:Context3D;
...
_context3D = stage3D.context3D;
```

And wmode is set to direct in html.

Comment: how did you construct your _context3D ?

Comment: question is updated

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, you might have hardware acceleration disable. Right-click on an instance of the Flash Player in your browser and select settings. In the first tab, you should have hardware acceleration checked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your graphics-card isn't supported by the new Flash player? There's some more information about graphics-card compatibility over in [this thread in the Adobe forums](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/802404).

Comment: I had checked my card by d3dcaps yesterday. My card is Nvidia GTX465, it can run the zombie demo perfectly.